# how to change brightness/contrast and hue of image using jslider

Tags: java, swing, jslider

I am trying to change the brightness and contrast of image using jslider but somehow it constantly changes only the brightness of image. Below is the code snippet. Just let me know what is problem.

Code:

```
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) 
{
    if(e.getSource()==js)
    {
        rescale=new RescaleOp(scaleFactor, offset, null);
        if(js.getValue()>=50)
            scaleFactor=(float)(js.getMaximum()/(2*js.getValue()));

      else 
            scaleFactor=(float)(js.getMaximum()/(js.getValue()));
        System.out.println(scaleFactor+""+js.getValue());
        imgmodify=rescale.filter(img, imgmodify);
        img=imgmodify;
        jif.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img)));
        jif.repaint();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance..:D

Owhhh sorry guys I forgot to tell you the name of object and for what they stands for...

1. js - JSlider
2. jif - JInternalFrame
3. img - BufferedImage
4. imgmodify - BufferedImage

Comment: `js` seems a JSlider object...but, what kind of object is `jif`? And...`imgmodify` is a BufferedImage, isn't? I ask it to clarify your code...

Comment: Your calculations look a little wrong (don't know if it will give the effect you want though) but `js.getMaximum()/js.getValue()` could result in 0.  Instead you should be using `(float)js.getMaximum()/(float)js.getValue()`

Comment: Don't you have to move the line `rescale=new RescaleOp(scaleFactor, offset, null);` to *after* you computed `scaleFactor`?

Comment: Examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A230513+RescaleOp).

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: andrew I think you are quite angry one me I don't know y but here I am      here to discuss my problem I know I haven't post the question correctly. I will try to improve but please right now I want to solve the problem which I am facing